# How to set up a pre-chat form in Smooch web messenger

Tags: smooch

I'd like to ask users for their name and email when they open the Smooch web widget, before the chat can be started. Similar to what Frank & Oak does: https://global.frankandoak.com/

I'm not very technical but can find my way around some HTML, CSS and even some javascript. I was hoping someone at Smooch would see my post and provide me with guidance on how to implement this :)

I'd need the name and email to be sent to Front (which I'm using to handle Smooch messages).

I know this might be a lot to ask, but if you find the time to help me, you can then add the answer to your documentation, which would be really cool for non-technical users like me.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

From [Smooch Web Messenger FAQ](https://docs.smooch.io/faq/web-messenger/)

**How can I capture user’s info before starting the conversation with the user on the web?**

You can create a form on your website and pass us the info in `Smooch.init()`.